# Unable to replay the audio file using just_audio plugin in Flutter windows

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to play audio file from asset on calling REST API using just_audio plugin. It can play the audio file only for the  first time.
I want to replay the audio every time I call API but I am unable to do that. The service is calling correctly but the sound file not playing neither it is giving any exception

Here is my code snippet:

```html
 socket.on('new_item', (data) async {
          print(' RECEIVED: $data');
          try {
           await player.setAsset('assets/tone.mp3');
           player.play();
          } catch (eror) {
            print('PLAY ERROR: $eror');
          }

        });
```

Can anyone help me with this issue.
Thanks

Comment: there is an issue but workaround is to reset the asset, file.